# Get The Object Pointer Is Pointing To

Tags: c++

I have a QList which I have inserted pointers of objects into. I am trying to iterate through this QList to read the name of these objects. Whenever I do so, I am getting the address of these objects as oppose to reading the object name itself. I am wondering how would I be able to read the object name instead of the address?

```
QList<MyObject*> newObjectList;
QList<MyObject*>::iterator i;

MyObject *pNewObject = new MyObject(name);
MyObject.append(pNewObject); 

for (i = newObjectList.begin(); i != newObjectList.end(); i++) {
    cout << "\n" << *i << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you're dereferencing i, you need to call the function to get the name from your object. Something like this:

```
for (i = newObjectList.begin(); i != newObjectList.end(); i++) {
    // i right now is the iterator, and points to a pointer. So this will need to be
    // dereferenced twice.
    cout << "\n" << (*i)->getName() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked:) Is there an alternative to using the arrow notation ( -> )?

Comment: You could just do two dereferences with *: `(*(*i)).getName();`

Answer (score 5):

When you derenference the iterator i (i.e. `*i`) you a a reference to an object of type `MyObject*` which is a pointer, you have to dereference that again to get a reference to your object:

```
*(*i)
```

Comment: `**i` is enough, parentheses aren't necessary.

Comment: I just tried that by changing the line to "cout << "\n" << *(*i) << "\n";" but I got the error "C678: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'QTextStream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"